# set file permissions on amazon s3 in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3

I'm uploading a file to my S3 bucket, and I want it to have public read permission. It seems like it should be simple, but like many things in my life, it is not. Looking for answers, the closest hint I've found is:

> Add a header to your PUT request: x-amz-acl: public-read

which seems simple enough, but I'm using AWSS3TransferUtitlity, not PUT, and trying to set the requestHeader on the AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression fails - setValue: forRequestHeader: is not recognized so I'm using requestParamaters instead, but that doesn't work either. I've searched and read till my eyes are bleary. Can someone help, please?

My code so far:

```
    AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression *expression = [AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression new];
 //   expression.uploadProgress = self.uploadProgress;
    [expression.requestParameters setValue:@"public-read" forKey:@"x-amz-acl"];
    AWSTask *atask;
    AWSS3TransferUtility *transferUtility = [AWSS3TransferUtility defaultS3TransferUtility];
    NSLog(@"started file trans: %@", self.fileToSend.fileURL);
    [atask = [transferUtility uploadFile:self.fileToSend.fileURL
                                  bucket:S3BucketName
                                    key:self.fileToSend.fileName
                             contentType:self.fileToSend.mimeType
                              expression:expression
                         completionHander:self.completionHandler]
                        continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
```

EDIT:
Some progress. I found I was using an outdated version of the SDK and uptodate version of the documentation. Another dumb mistake. Anyway, after updating the SDK and recompiling, it runs, but creates and exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: `'[<__NSDictionary0 0x12ed0c280> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key x-amz-acl.'`

EDIT:
OK. Fixed. With combination of hints, a step back, I changed my request header line to :

```
[expression setValue:@"public-read" forRequestHeader:@"x-amz-acl"];
```

Thanks to the responders.

Comment: Have you updated bucket policy on AWS S3 console?

Comment: you can set public read to 'S3BucketName' name from AWS..

Comment: Why `forKey:@"x-amz-grant-read-acl"];` instead of `forKey:@"x-amz-acl"];`?

Comment: @Michael - I've since changed to @"x-amz-acl" and now get an exception: 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSDictionary0 0x12ed0c280> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key x-amz-acl.' Even the exception is progress, though.

Answer (score 5):

In swift use like this,

```
let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
expression.setValue("public-read", forRequestHeader:"x-amz-acl")
```

Comment: One line making me crazy for a week, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I added it as a query param and it seemed to work:

```
let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
expression.setValue("public-read", forRequestParameter:"x-amz-acl")
```

No docs whatsoever, so who knows.
Once again, bravo, AWS.